# No AAAA responses from Google DNS

Tags: windows-7, dns, ipv6, tunnel, google-public-dns

I just set up a HE tunnel on my Windows 7 PC, and while i can browse to http://[2a01:3f0:0:a::186]/ i cannot browse to http://ipv6only.bredbandskollen.se which is their FQDN. Also, the speedtest flash doesnt load as its probably trying to do a lookup of an ipv6 address to pull its data.

My DNS servers are set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. If i do:

```
nslookup nslookup -type=aaaa ipv6.bredbandskollen.se 8.8.8.8
```

i get a this response:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** Inga IPv6 address-poster (AAAA) är tillgängliga för ipv6.bredbandskollen.se
```

Translated to english that basically means that there are no ipv6-posts (aaaa) available for that domain.

says:

```
IPv6 connections work, but connections using DNS names do not use IPv6. For some reason, your browser or your OS is not doing IPv6 DNS 'AAAA' lookups.
```

Here is my ipconfig:

```
IP-konfiguration för Windows

Värddatornamn . . . . . . . . . . : ma****
Primärt DNS-suffix. . . . . . . . :
Nodtyp. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP-routning aktiverat . . . . . . : Nej (No)
WINS-proxy aktiverat. . . . . . . : Nej (No)
Söklista för DNS-suffix . . . . . : Hilton.com

Ethernet-anslutning Anslutning till lokalt nätverk:

Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . : Hilton.com
Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connect

Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 20-CF-30-76-**-**
DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja
Länklokal IPv6-adress . . . . . . : fe80::299e:4c8:**:**(Standard)
IPv4-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 12.207.**.**(Standard)
Nätmask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.128
Lånet erhölls . . . . . . . . . . : den 18 maj 2011 19:47:07
Lånet upphör. . . . . . . . . . . : den 21 maj 2011 23:34:01
Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . : 12.207.**.*
DHCP-server . . . . . . . . . . . : 12.207.**.*
IAID för DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . : 23703****
DUID för DHCPv6-klient. . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-0C-17-A6-20-CF-*-*-*-*

DNS-servrar . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                    8.8.4.4
NetBIOS över TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiverat (Enabled)

Tunnelanslutning: isatap.Hilton.com:

Tillstånd . . . . . . . . . . . . : Frånkopplad
Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . : Hilton.com
Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja

Tunnelanslutning: IP6Tunnel:

Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . : Hilton.com
Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Direct Point-to-point Adapater
Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja
IPv6-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:*:*::*(Standard)
Länklokal IPv6-adress . . . . . . : fe80::84e5:*:*:*(Standard)
Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:*:*::*
DNS-servrar . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                    8.8.4.4
NetBIOS över TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Inaktiverat (Disabled)

Tunnelanslutning: 6TO4 Adapter:

Tillstånd . . . . . . . . . . . . : Frånkopplad (Disconnected)
Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . :
Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja

Tunnelanslutning: Reusable Microsoft 6To4 Adapter:

Tillstånd . . . . . . . . . . . . : Frånkopplad (Disconnected)
Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . :
Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #2
Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja
```

And this are the commands used to set up the tunnel

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 12.207.*.* 216.66.80.26
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel 2001:470:*:*::*
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel 2001:470:*:*::*
```

Comment: I checked _network.dns.disableIPv6_ in _about:config_ in the Firefox 4 that i use and it was false. What more could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a fluke - some DNS problems go away themself.

It works here:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ipv6.bredbandskollen.se
Address:  2a01:3f0:0:a::186
```

The again, 8.8.8.8 might be more than one server, so while mine is working, yours might have a problem.

Another problem: Sometimes people do filter DNS packages. The filter might not know about AAAA records yet. Your DNS suffix (Hilton.com) implies that such filtering is possible.

If your IPv6 tunnel is up, try one of the [OpenDNS IPv6 DNS](http://www.opendns.com/about/announcements/213/) servers:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa ipv6.bredbandskollen.se 2620:0:ccc::2
```

Comment: Running that OpendDNS query returned a pretty interesting answer: 

C:\Users\Maciej Swic>nslookup -type=aaaa ipv6.bredbandskollen.se 2620:0:ccc::2
**DNS request timed out.**
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  **UnKnown**
Address:  2620:0:ccc::2

Non-authoritative answer:
Namn:    ipv6.bredbandskollen.se
Address:  **2a01:3f0:0:a::186**

Comment: So it both timed out and i got an answer. And as mentioned before the tunnel is up, i can go to http://[ipv6-addr], just cant to lookups.

Comment: I get this too, seems like reverse loopkup is not set up for this address.

Comment: Upon adding 2620:0:ccc::2 and 2620:0:ccd::2 to my DNS servers, i can now go to ipv6only.bredbandskollen.se and the flash loads. Very strange Google wont return AAAA records but i guess its their fault then...